# How to display JfreeChart ( ChartPanel ) in Jpanel generated by NetBeans

Tags: java, jpanel, jfreechart

i've generated a gui using netbeans gui generator. I have two panel and in one of this i want to show a chartpanel. The code generated by netbeans is:

```
private void initComponents() {

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();

        org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
            .add(0, 394, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
            .add(0, 294, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout layout = new org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout(this);
        this.setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
            .add(0, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
                .add(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .add(jPanel1, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addContainerGap()))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
            .add(0, 300, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
                .add(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .add(jPanel1, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addContainerGap()))
        );
    }
```

What i've done to add the chartpanel to jpanel is :

```
TimeSeriesCollection dataset = new TimeSeriesCollection();
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                TimeSeries pop = new TimeSeries("try "+i, Day.class);
                pop.add(new Day(10+i, 1+i, 2004+i), 100*(i+2));
                pop.add(new Day(10+1*i, 1+2+i, 2004+i+1), 150*(i+2));
                pop.add(new Day(10+2*i, 1+2*i, 2004+i+2), 150*(i+3));
                pop.add(new Day(10+3*i, 1+2*i, 2004+i+3), 150*(i+4));
                pop.add(new Day(10+4*i, 1+2*i, 2004+i+10), 150*(i+5));
                dataset.addSeries(pop);
            }
            TimeSeries pop = new TimeSeries("Try asjhaihsiuahsiuahiushaiushiauhsiuhasiua"+100, Day.class);
            int i=5;
                pop.add(new Day(1, 1+i, 2004+i), 100*(i+2));
                pop.add(new Day(2, 1+2+i, 2004+i+1), 150*(i+2));
                pop.add(new Day(3, 1+2*i, 2004+i+2), 150*(i+3));
                pop.add(new Day(4, 1+2*i, 2004+i+3), 150*(i+4));
                pop.add(new Day(5, 1+2*i, 2004+i+10), 1500*(i+5));
                dataset.addSeries(pop);
            JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createTimeSeriesChart(
                    "Population of CSC408 Town",
                    "Date",
                    "Population",
                    dataset,
                    true,
                    true,
                    false);
            ChartPanel p = new ChartPanel(chart);

            jPanel1.add(p);
```

But chartpanel won't show inside jpanel.. what can i do? can you help me?

Comment: I'm not a Swing expert but it could be because the GroupLayout built by Netbeans has no place left for your chart - so when you add it, it is there but not visible... Maybe try `jPanel1.setLayout(new xxx)` before adding the chart to see if it is there. If it is you know where the problem is... Not sure what xxx you could use, maybe just a default `new GroupLayout()` would work

Comment: i try ChartPanel p = new ChartPanel(chart);
            jPanel1.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            jPanel1.add(p,BorderLayout.CENTER); but nothing :(

Answer (score 0):

set Layout in your NetBeans panel to BorderLayout (by right click on it from design preview then set layout, or do it from code Panel.setLayout ) , after that when you want to show your chart panel, just add the chart panel into parent panel and ask for repaint.

```
netbeansPanel.add(charPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
netbeansPanel.validate();
```

also you can remove the panel in case if you want to update the chart with new one:

```
netbeansPanel.removeAll();
netbeansPanel.add(charPanel);
netbeansPanel.validate();
```

Comment: if i do Dimension d = new Dimension(300,200); 
            p.setSize(d); 
            p.setPreferredSize(d); 
            BorderLayout layout = new BorderLayout(); 
            this.setLayout(layout); 
            this.add(p,BorderLayout.CENTER);  it works better, but if i use this.getSize() it return dimension 0,0.. i don't know why...

Comment: why you want to call this.getSize()? this is the size of parent component. all you should do after set parent panel layout is add the new panel into it, and layout manager will handle the size for you.

Comment: it doesn't work like you say.. i try to set the dimension of chart with jPanel1 size but nothing...

Comment: don't forget to repaint your panel after adding the chart, using netbeansPanel.validate();